ResourcseServer Spring Boot
i use reousrce server to authorize users, i have own ovverided method loadusername, which call external server to get user data, external server has not authority system, he's hide in docker network, not exposing ports, i make /oauth/token endpoint public, but i got an error 2024-11-26 12:21:12.375  WARN 13891 --- [nio-8002-exec-2] c.n.p.c.security.OAuth2TokenService      : Unable to log user {response: {timestamp=2024-11-26T11:21:12.342+0000, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, message=Request method 'POST' not supported, path=/oauth/token}}
i don't know why i got 405, i add, in main it works, in my branch not, im looking for changes which can destroy it, but find nothing changed in resource server configuration

If any more details needed, comment i will try to give it

Problem was be in mapping, wrong declare another controller, and this make error in resource server idk why, but fixing maping i fix resource server
